# Memory leak using multiple boost::connect on single slot_type

Tags: c++, boost, memory-leaks, boost-bind, boost-signals

I'm using `boost::signals` and leaking memory when I try to connect multiple signals to a single `slot_type`. I've seen this same leak reported on various forums, but can't find any that mention the correct way to do this, or any workaround.

What I am trying to do:

I am trying to pass the result of `boost::bind()` into a function. In this function, I want to connect multiple signals to that result. The first connect works fine, but every connect after the first will leak a handle.

Here is some sample code:

```
typedef boost::signal0<void> LeakSignalType;

class CalledClass
{
   /* ... */
   void connectToSlots(LeakSignalType::slot_type &aSlot)
   {
        LeakSignalType *sig;
        std::list<LeakSignalType*> sigList;
        std::list<LeakSignalType*>::iterator sigIter;

        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            /*Connect signals to the passed slot */
            sig = new LeakSignalType;
            sig->connect(aSlot);
            sigList.push_back(sig);
        }
        for(sigIter = sigList.begin(); sigIter != sigList.end(); sigIter++)
        {
            /* Undo everything we just did */
            delete *sigIter;
        }
        sigList.clear();
        /*Everything should be cleaned up now */
   }
   /* ... */
}

class CallingClass : public boost::signals::trackable
{
   CalledClass calledInstance;
   /* ... */
   void boundFunction(int i)
   {
   /*Do Something*/
   }

   void connectSignals()
   {
       calledInstance.connectToSlots(boost::bind( &CallingClass::boundFunction, this, 1));
   }
   /* ... */
};
```

Now call `CallingClass::connectSignals()`.

I expect that the call to `connectToSlots` will connect 50 signals to a single slot, then disconnect and clean up all of those signals. What actually happens is that 1 signal completely cleans up, then the remaining 49 partially clean up, but leak some memory.

What is the correct way to pass a slot into a function to use multiple times? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Can you be more specific about what gets leaked?  You're calling `delete` so the destructor is being called, right?

Comment: Yes, the problem is I don't know exactly what's being leaked. If I changed the for loop's `i < 50` to `i < 1` so the loop only ran once, there would be no leak. However, there is some problem with calling multiple `connect`s on the same `slot_type.`  Our allocator has an 'open handle count' that shows that for every connect past the first one, the delete leaves a single handle open. Either Boost is leaking, or, more likely, I am misusing Boost but don't know the correct way to do this.

Comment: Does `LeakSignalType` have a non-trivial destructor?  Can you put a counter in there to verify that it's being called 50 times? -- You might be better off using a container of `shared_ptr` objects instead of pointers, then you can just clear it or let it go out of scope.

Comment: At the top of the code, `typedef boost::signal0<void> LeakSignalType;` makes `LeakSignalType` just a `boost::signal` . I've stepped through the code enough to ensure that the destructors are getting called, but I get lost trying to follow `boost` code so don't know exactly what's not getting freed.  Would a `shared_ptr` help fix the leak, or just save me using `delete`.  This example isn't my actual use of the code, but the minimum code I could come up with to display the leak. I'll try using `shared_ptr` and see what happens though. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Oh, I missed that, sorry.  The docs say that a signal is disconnected automatically when destroyed, so I don't see what might be happening.  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/signals/tutorial.html#id1655908

Comment: Yeah, I'm lost too :). I have spent the last 4 days going over the docs and forum posts. I've found a couple of forum posts with the same problem, but unfortunately they have had no resolutions (and have been dated back as far as 2006) so I may just be SOL.

Comment: I don't know whether this will be a workaround or not, but have you tried (if feasible) manually disconnecting the slot from all the signals? You will need to keep the connection objects returned by connect(), this will not be nice or clean, but might work.

Comment: Keeping the connections around and manually disconnecting them doesn't work, because the `disconnect()` function checks if the slot is connected before doing anything, so won't do anything past the first disconnect. I'm trying to see if I can manually save whatever pointer Boost is losing and delete it myself.

Comment: I think I may have found a workaround manually deleting the pointer, and have posted it below. Thanks for pointing me in that direction, dribeas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's a bug.  If you collapse it down to a tiny example, e.g.:

```
void boundFunction(int) { }
typedef boost::signal0<void> LeakSignalType;
LeakSignalType::slot_type aSlot = boost::bind(&::boundFunction, 1);
LeakSignalType sig1, sig2;
sig1.connect(aSlot);
sig2.connect(aSlot);
```

and trace the allocations, you'll find that one object (a `boost::signals::detail::signal_base_impl::iterator`) allocated at line 75 of `boost/lib/signals/src/signal_base.cpp` is not freed up.

```
// Allocate storage for an iterator that will hold the point of
// insertion of the slot into the list. This is used to later remove
// the slot when it is disconnected.
std::auto_ptr<iterator> saved_iter(new iterator);
```

On the first `connect`, this iterator is attached to a fresh connection object, where `signal_data` is NULL:

```
data->watch_bound_objects.get_connection()->signal_data =
  saved_iter.release();
```

On the second `connect`, however, the same connection object is reused, and the same line blindly overwrites the original pointer value.  The second object is cleaned up, but the first is not.

As verification, a breakpoint in `signal_base_impl::slot_disconnected`, the only place where `signal_data` is cleaned up, is only triggered once.

I tracked this down in 1.39.0, but it looks like it's the same in 1.40.0.

You could modify `boost::signals::detail::signal_base_impl::connect_slot` to clean up any previous iterator value it finds in the `signal_data` field of an existing connection, if you're comfortable making such a change and running a custom build of Boost.

It might be better to just make sure you're only setting these up a fixed number of times and live with a few small memory leaks that you know won't grow over time.

Update:

I was going to submit this to the Boost bug tracker, but it's already there.  This is a much smaller test case, however.

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/738

Opened 3 years ago, not assigned to any milestone :-[

Comment: Certainly not what I was hoping to hear, but at least now I know that it's workaround time instead of "how am I supposed to use this" time :).  Thanks for finding that!

Answer (score 0):

For other people's reference, I am having some luck maintaining my own copy of `signal_data`, and deleting it before deleting the signal. Don't know of any side effects, YMMV.

Something like this:

```
typedef boost::signal0<void> LeakSignalType;
struct LeakSignalStruct
{
    LeakSignalType  signal;
    /* A pointer to keep track of the pointer Boost loses */
    boost::signals::detail::named_slot_map_iterator *signal_data;
};

class CalledClass
{
   /* ... */
   void connectToSlots(LeakSignalType::slot_type &aSlot)
   {
        LeakSignalStruct *sig;
        std::list<LeakSignalStruct*> sigList;
        std::list<LeakSignalStruct*>::iterator sigIter;

        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            /*Connect signals to the passed slot */
            sig = new LeakSignalStruct;
            sig->connect(aSlot);
            /* Make a backup of the reference that Boost will lose */
            sig->signal_data = (boost::signals::detail::named_slot_map_iterator*)connection.get_connection()->signal_data;
            sigList.push_back(sig);
        }

        /* Boost remembers the last signal_data and will delete it itself,
           so we better lose our reference to avoid double-delete */
        sig->signal_data = NULL;

        for(sigIter = sigList.begin(); sigIter != sigList.end(); sigIter++)
        {
            /* Undo everything we just did */
            /* Boost lost this reference, so we delete it ourselves */
            delete (*sigIter)->signal_data;
            delete *sigIter;
        }
        sigList.clear();
        /*Everything should be cleaned up now */
   }
   /* ... */
};

class CallingClass : public boost::signals::trackable
{
   CalledClass calledInstance;
   /* ... */
   void boundFunction(int i)
   {
   /*Do Something*/
   }

   void connectSignals()
   {
       calledInstance.connectToSlots(boost::bind( &CallingClass::boundFunction, this, 1));
   }
   /* ... */
};
```